# Creating an edition of a poet's Complete Poems: LaTeX to TEI, or TEI to LaTex?

Tags: conversion, tei

I'm doing some of the typesetting and editing work on a new edition of a poet's Complete Poems. I want to create a TEI edition, as it will enable me to encode all sorts of metadata with the text. However, working with LaTeX is more straightforward and, crucially, automates the addition of line numbers (and various other things) via the poemscol package.

So, should I start by creating a LaTeX version and then generate a TEI version from that, or do I create the TEI version first, and then convert from that to LaTex? What are the pros and cons of each approach? And what is the best way to carry out each conversion?

Comment: You should create a markdown version and generate TEI and LaTeX form that, using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Sorry for my stupid question, what is TEI?

Comment: Thank you @DG'! What are the advantages to that particular workflow?

Comment: @AndréC not a stupid question at all! It's an XML format; you can find more info at https://wiki.tei-c.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: @Jim – you can maintain one simple source and generate multiple target formats. Also, you can adjust your outpu, using filters: https://pandoc.org/filters.html

Comment: Depending on the actual source, you could try using TEI and ConTeXt, it has great XML capabilities. But to assess your usecase, you should give more information...

Comment: @Jim – The advantages are simplicity and transparency.

Comment: @DG' thanks again :) my usecase is compiling the text of a ~1,500 page multi-volume complete poems. TEI appeals because there is a lot of meta-data associated with these poems (real names, lengthy quotation from other texts, etc) and TEI seems to be a goo way to encode that. I was drawn to LaTeX because the poemscol package will let me add line numbers easily, and I like the syntax in general. Once I've done the typesetting I'll pass .docx files over the other editors who will provide a commentary.

Comment: Just for the record, adding linenumbers is quite straightforward under ConTeXt, you don't need to load any package.

Comment: @sztruks thanks, good to know. poemscol does all sorts of things that are useful when setting an edition of poetry so I need it anyway, but it's useful to know about ConTeXt. The way that line numbering works in poetry is also quite specific, and I'm not sure if ConTeXt would do everything the right way as easily as poemscol does (I've had a quick Google but can't figure it out).

Answer (score 5):

It's easier to make an omelette from an egg than an egg from an omelette...

Coding a simple document in latex is likely to be simpler and you can probably convert it to get passable TEI XML. So that is an option.

But if you want to really use TEI features and really use the full extent of its annotation mechanisms, then there is no substitute for coding the XML directly in an XML editor and then converting to latex as needed (the TEI have standard tools for that). Arranging that every TEI feature that you need can be marked up in latex and survive a transformation in that direction is likely to be harder than writing the TEI XML directly.

Answer (score 3):

There is a XSLT script for transforming TEI into LaTeX, written by the late, great Sebastian Rahtz. I haven't played with it, but it seems to transform TEI into LaTeX using the eledmac package, which is the most widely used package for critical editions (originally written by my graduate student John Lavagnino). My sense, however, is that no transformation between the two languages will be so easy as not to require quite a bit of hand tweaking, and there will always be a difference between a program designed to manage a database of the text's features and a program designed to manage its appearance on the page; each will do what it is designed to do better than it can do the other program's task.  I had in mind to write an XSLT script that would transform TEI into LaTeX using my own poemscol package, but I don't at the moment have enough of a grasp of XSLT to pull it off, and I didn't imagine the script would have many users other than me.

Going from LaTeX to TEI is rather harder. TEI assumes (as does eledmac) that each element is concentrically contained in a larger element. Stanzas do not cross the boundary between poems, lines do not cross the boundary between stanzas, and so on. Now sometimes lines do jump the boundaries between stanzas. Robert Penn Warren often has a line that is broken in the middle not just by a "line break" (it's not really a line break, since it's one line, but there is a line feed between the two halves of the line, and the second half is set horizontally flush with the end of the end of the first) but by a stanza break. Carl Phillips has such lines too.

You can code these things in TEI and in eledmac, but in both cases it requires a certain amount of finesse, because to do so runs against the grain of the program. You can code these quite easily in poemscol, but there is a price, in that you can't just transform your poemscol file into TEI but have to manually edit every place where one of these little monsters occurs.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the very relevant comments given above, I would like to point out the existence of the `ekdosis` package the first version of which was released on August 14, 2020. In addition to printed texts, `ekdosis` can convert `.tex` source files so as to produce TEI xml compliant critical editions.

- Link to the CTAN page: https://ctan.org/pkg/ekdosis
- Link to an [article about the coding method published in *JDMHD*](https://jdmdh.episciences.org/6536).

Comment: Thank you, Robert, that's a really interesting development: I shall look into it.